# HTML5 canvas curve anti-aliasing worse than SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I just started to study canvas, drawing a circle and found its anti-aliasing curve was worse than a circle in SVG.

My code is like this:

```
context.arc(0, 0, radius, 0.5 * Math.PI, 0.5 * Math.PI - radian, true);
```

I reversed the y-axis to make it natural for me. I have already scale the canvas to make it adapt retina display.

The result on my Mac picture is [here](http://s27.postimg.org/ogwlhdggz/Screen_Shot_2014_06_27_at_20_21_49.png).

My complete code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/btfk6/).

Update:
My code is doing an animation of completing a circle.

I just noticed that if fps is set to 1-3, anti-aliasing is actually applying. Really strange.

Comment: You should know that SVG is vector graphics while Canvas is raster graphics. SVG will never deteriorate when scaled (Hint: "SV").

Comment: But canvas and screen resolution ratio is 1:1. They should have a same level of anti-aliasing (if not is it possible to improve anti-aliasing level?). I just tried increase canvas size to 8x: it is still worse than SVG but it is already too slow.

Comment: have you tried different browsers?

Comment: @mb21 I have tried it on Firefox, Chrome and Safari on OS X Yosemite & Mavericks. It seems that this relates to FPS. Higher fps could deteriorate anti-aliasing result.